# How to copy a cursor of 11 columns and 7 rows in a 2d string array on Android

Tags: android, android-cursor

I have a table of 11 columns and 7 rows of string values

I hava a list of my textviews of size 77 elements

I want to display my data on my textviews which are on 7 columns of 11 rows and I am rather confused I have tried:

```
String[][] mazeArray = new String[7][11]; 
            int nk=0;
            GetDataBack.moveToFirst();
            while (!GetDataBack.isAfterLast() && nk<7) {

                mazeArray[nk][0] = GetDataBack.getString(GetDataBack.getColumnIndex("c_one"));
                mazeArray[nk][1] = GetDataBack.getString(GetDataBack.getColumnIndex("c_two"));
                mazeArray[nk][2] = GetDataBack.getString(GetDataBack.getColumnIndex("c_three"));
                mazeArray[nk][3] = GetDataBack.getString(GetDataBack.getColumnIndex("c_four"));
                mazeArray[nk][4] = GetDataBack.getString(GetDataBack.getColumnIndex("c_five"));
                mazeArray[nk][5] = GetDataBack.getString(GetDataBack.getColumnIndex("c_six"));
                mazeArray[nk][6] = GetDataBack.getString(GetDataBack.getColumnIndex("c_seven"));
                mazeArray[nk][7] = GetDataBack.getString(GetDataBack.getColumnIndex("c_eight"));
                mazeArray[nk][8] = GetDataBack.getString(GetDataBack.getColumnIndex("c_nine"));
                mazeArray[nk][9] = GetDataBack.getString(GetDataBack.getColumnIndex("c_ten"));
                mazeArray[nk][10] = GetDataBack.getString(GetDataBack.getColumnIndex("c_eleven"));
                nk=nk+1;
                GetDataBack.moveToNext();
            }


for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
    {
       finalTotalList.get(11 * i + j).setText(mazeArray[i][j]);
    }

}
```

What I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use i and j for your `finalTotalList.get()` call. Use an incrementing value. Do something like `int a = 0;` outside of your for loop then `finalTotalList.get(a++).setText(mazeArray[i][j]);`. This will keep a value for your TextView position without any convoluted math.

Comment: Yes this seems to solve the problem thank you